# If $\sin^{-1}\frac{2a}{1+a^2}-\cos^{-1}\frac{1-b^2}{1+b^2}=\tan^{-1}\frac{2x}{1-x^2}$ then what is value of x?

Tags: trigonometry, inverse

If $\sin^{-1}\frac{2a}{1+a^2}-\cos^{-1}\frac{1-b^2}{1+b^2}=\tan^{-1}\frac{2x}{1-x^2}$ then what is value of x?
Solution 
$\tan^{-1}x=\tan^{-1}a-\tan^{-1}b=\tan^{-1}\frac{a-b}{1+ab}$
x=$\frac{a-b}{1+ab}$

i have a doubt what is $\tan^{-1}a$ and $\tan^{-1}b$ and how come $\tan^{-1}x=\tan^{-1}a-\tan^{-1}b$?

Comment: Related : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1339791/solve-for-x-from-an-equation-containing-inverse-trigonometric-functions

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hint:

Assume a=tan(y) and similarly for x and b .
Solve the identity and replace y with $tan^{-1}$b .
You will get your expression.

Use [this](http://upload.wikimedia.org/math/3/b/6/3b692046deb671efee59c8f28acabd74.png) ,[this](http://upload.wikimedia.org/math/2/1/0/2106e15560a21a8694042a2eecd2e120.png) and [this](http://upload.wikimedia.org/math/e/e/8/ee8b4e6c069c126d8136a88c55378c2c.png) from [here](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities) for help with those identities.