# Solve for $x$ from an equation containing inverse trigonometric functions

Tags: trigonometry, inverse

> How to solve the following for $x$?
>   $$
>   \sin^{-1}\left(\frac{2a}{1+a^{2}}\right)+
>   \sin^{-1}\left(\frac{2b}{1+b^{2}}\right)= 
>   2 \tan^{-1}(x )
> $$

What conditions apply?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\tan^{-1}a=A\implies -\dfrac\pi2\le A\le\dfrac\pi2\iff-\pi\le2A\le\pi$  and $a=\tan A$

$$\sin^{-1}\left[\dfrac{2\tan A}{1+\tan^2A}\right]=\sin^{-1}(\sin2A)$$

$$=\begin{cases} 2A &\mbox{if } -\dfrac\pi2\le2A\le\dfrac\pi2 \\ 
\pi-2A & \mbox{if }  \dfrac\pi2<2A\le\pi \\ -\pi-2A & \mbox{if } -\pi\le2A<-\dfrac\pi2 \end{cases}  $$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: Let $\theta = \sin^{-1}\left(\dfrac{2a}{1+a^2}\right) \Rightarrow \sin \theta = \dfrac{2a}{1+a^2}$, and similarly $\sin \beta = \dfrac{2b}{1+b^2}$. Thus:

$\tan^{-1}x = \dfrac{\theta}{2}+\dfrac{\beta}{2} \Rightarrow x = \tan\left(\dfrac{\theta}{2}+\dfrac{\beta}{2}\right)$. You can compute $\tan\left(\dfrac{\theta}{2}\right)$, and $\tan\left(\dfrac{\beta}{2}\right)$ using the above equations, then find $x$.

Comment: Using http://planetmath.org/weierstrasssubstitutionformulas $\tan\dfrac\theta2$ will have two values, right?  How to select the right ones?

Comment: You can show it can only take on $1$ value.

Comment: How to show that, my friend?

Answer (score 0):

$$
  \sin^{-1}\left(\frac{2a}{1+a^{2}}\right)+
  \sin^{-1}\left(\frac{2b}{1+b^{2}}\right)= 
  2 \tan^{-1}(x )
$$

Draw a right angled triangle with sides $$ (1+a^2), 2a, (1-a^2) $$ with all $ \tan^{-1}$

It now becomes

$$
  \tan^{-1}\left(\frac{2a}{1-a^{2}}\right)+
  \tan^{-1}\left(\frac{2b}{1-b^{2}}\right)= 
  2 \tan^{-1}(x )
$$

and proceed using double angle for tan as in the question you gave just alongside.

Comment: The triangle is possible only if $a,1-a^2>0$ implies $0<a<1$, right? What about the other cases?

Comment: Pythagoras  needs  only  squared numbers sum equality to hold. Argument of $ tan^{-1}$ is unbounded. Geometric construction needs $ a<1$, it is only an aid to get our relations together.